# Docker Error : kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException in Kafka shell

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to run kafka using docker.

I started kafka service.

> docker-compose ps

```
     Name                        Command               State                         Ports
```

**kafka-docker_kafka_1**              start-kafka.sh                   **Up**      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
**kafka-docker_zookeeper_1**   /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   **Up**      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp

**docker-compose.yml**

> cat docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: 36000
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

When I tried to create a topic by entering inside shell, it's throwing the below error.

> ./start-kafka-shell.sh kafka **zookeeper**:2181
>
> bash-4.4# $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic sentiment --partitions 1 --zookeeper $ZK --replication-factor 1

```
[2019-02-12 08:07:59,097] WARN Session 0x0 for server zookeeper:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:277)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:287)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1021)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1064)
```

**Tried 2 possibilities:**

1. Got timeout exception on changing hostname :zookeeper(though I mentioned the same in docker-compose.yml ) to ip: 0.0.0.0

> ./start-kafka-shell.sh kafka **0.0.0.0**:2181
>
> bash-4.4# $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic sentiment --partitions 1 --zookeeper $ZK --replication-factor 1

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:268)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:264)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:97)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1694)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:57)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

2. Inorder to avoid the above error, I increased the timeout parameter from 6000 to 36000 in docker-compose.yml --> KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: 36000

I'm getting the same timeout error.

Comment: you should introduce host address and port of the Zookeeper for the property --zookeeper. Suppose the zookeeper process is running on localhost: `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic sentiment --partitions 1 --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1`

Comment: You can find a functioning Docker Compose here: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.1.0-post/examples/kafka-single-node/docker-compose.yml

You can find important information about networking in Docker with Kafka here: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @Soheil : I have already given hostname and port while starting the shell. It's mentioned in the post.Tried with zookeeper:2181 and 0.0.0.0:2181. One is giving unresolved address resolution exception and other is giving timeout exception respectively.

Comment: Resolved.Answer:- Until you explicitly add `--net kafka-docker_default` to the `start-kafka-shell.sh` script, the internal docker DNS resolution for host `zookeeper` won't work, so further examples about producer/consumer cannot be run.

The correct script should look like this:#!/bin/bash
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net kafka-docker_default -e HOST_IP=$1 -e ZK=$2 -i -t wurstmeister/kafka /bin/bash

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not proper here to add *RESOLVED* or *SOLVED* to the title, and it is also not proper to edit the solution into the question. Instead, you should write an answer in the space below that is designed for that purpose; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information. If you don't want to write an answer, then you can delete the question using the link beneath the tags or wait to see if someone else posts an answer..

Comment: I don't know where that script exists, but I don't think you need it. Kafka should start as part of the container, and using the zookeeper in the environment variables. You should only need Zookeeper address on the CLI to create and describe topics

Comment: I did not found any solution for this but I have one alternative:
https://towardsdev.com/3-simple-steps-to-set-up-kafka-locally-using-docker-b07f71f0e2c9

This deploys zookeeper and kafka in same container so host entry issue with this.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of pre-built Kafka images. It's hard to tell what you're actually trying to do, but seems you're rebuilding an image? Or building your own?

You definitely don't need the zookeeper address as a parameter to start Kafka, though

That being said, 0.0.0.0 is not a real address to connect to. It's often used as a **bind address** meaning to "allow all connections to this server"

Then `zookeeper` service name is only resolvable within the Docker network, so that might explain why you need `--net`, but that implies you're using `docker run` for something, which again isn't clear given you're using Compose

If you want to get into a shell of the container, you should just be to use `docker-compose exec kafka bash`, and Zookeeper is already an environment variable of that container

So something like

`docker-compose exec kafka bash -c '$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic sentiment --partitions 1 --zookeeper $KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT --replication-factor 1'`

Answer (score 1):

yesterday I started use kafka in docker from https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker.git

my steps

```
https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker.git

nano kafka-docker/docker-compose.yml
```

my conf

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test-topic:5:2"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

after

```
docker-compose up -d 

docker-compose scale kafka=3
```

check docker container

```
$docker-compose ps
          Name                        Command               State                         Ports                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kafka-docker_kafka_1       start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:32784->9092/tcp                           
kafka-docker_kafka_2       start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:32785->9092/tcp                           
kafka-docker_kafka_3       start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:32786->9092/tcp                           
kafka-docker_zookeeper_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

or

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
1479a7dc96fa        wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:32785->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_2
08e5017dae2b        wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:32786->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_3
d4f3d17e81b2        wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:32784->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_1
72b0fbe553b5        wurstmeister/zookeeper   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   kafka-docker_zookeeper_1
```

after connect to kafka broker1 and get topics from zookeeper

```
$ docker exec -it kafka-docker_kafka_1 bash
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --list
sample
test-topic
bash-4.4#
```

get info by topics

```
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe --topic sample
Topic: sample   PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: 
    Topic: sample   Partition: 0    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002  Isr: 1002
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe --topic test-topic
Topic: test-topic   PartitionCount: 5   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: 
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003 Isr: 1001,1003
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001 Isr: 1002,1001
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 2    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002 Isr: 1003,1002
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 3    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002 Isr: 1001,1002
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 4    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003 Isr: 1002,1003
```

after create new topic

```
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --create --topic topic1 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2
Created topic topic1.
```

describe

```
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe --topic topic1
Topic: topic1   PartitionCount: 2   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: 
    Topic: topic1   Partition: 0    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001 Isr: 1003,1001
    Topic: topic1   Partition: 1    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002 Isr: 1001,1002
```

Comment: Everyone upvote this pls!
The github repo was great but the instructions were not clear. Appreciate the clear steps @Nikolay Baranenko

Answer (score 0):

In my case windows firewall was blocking docker containers. I ran below in powershell to resolve
Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfacealias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private